# Mapbox GL layer vertical offset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a 3d map with building extrusion and need to place some images on rooftops.

[image]
But I can't find out how to set layer or object vertical offset. It is positioned on the ground level only.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet implemented, being tracked at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3993